# Morning, Afternoon, Night Kanji

Tags: kanji, time

Learning the time of day I found that 朝 or あさ means morning, 昼 or ひる means afternoon, and 晚 I expected to be night but Google translate is saying it's moth for some reason. Does this 晚 only mean night when paired with certain characters?

Comment: Funnily enough, I have noticed a similar problem when google translate - Many, *many* single characters are incorrectly translated as moth. I have no idea why that happens... But it does. Here are some examples I found after 20 seconds of searching:「蜻 - dragonfly」「舘 - mansion, large building」. It seems to only really occur for single kanji that dont have a kunyomi reading, or at least not a common one.

Comment: @あらまあ I noticed the "moth" issue a while ago, in more than one language. I think someone (or a bunch of someones) is trolling google translate community https://translate.google.com/community translating everything as "moth". Nowadays Google translate is community-driven and not statistics-driven, and that system is great as long as there's not a lot of bad actors trolling in a synchronized manner.

Comment: @Arie Would be interesting if this bad actor was [Cicada](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicada_3301), huh?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Translate, and indeed just about any machine translation engine, is still often shit for the Japanese ↔ English language pair.  **Do not** rely on Google Translate to learn another language, especially when looking at a single word.

Here are some time-of-day terms:

- 朝【あさ】 = "morning"
- 昼【ひる】 = "day, afternoon"
- 晩【ばん】 = "evening"
- 夜【よる】 = "late evening, night"

See also this recent post: [What's the difference among 夜中, 真夜中 and 夜?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66662)

**PS:** For what it's worth, the actual word for "moth" is 蛾【が】.  I recommend that you use any of various online dictionaries when exploring a single word.  Here are some freebies:

- [Weblio Japanese ↔ English](https://ejje.weblio.jp/)
- [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/) (geared for native Japanese readers, but still offering some Japanese ↔ English content)
- [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/) (sometimes a bit dodgy, make sure to cross-check)
- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/) (full disclosure: I've helped edit a lot of the Japanese entries)

#### Digression, and example of the perils of machine translation

The original post included the kanji 晚, technically [Unicode codepoint 665A](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=665A).

[image]

The above is the 旧【きゅう】字【じ】体【たい】 or "old form" of the 新【しん】字【じ】体【たい】 or "new form" kanji 晩, technically [Unicode codepoint 6669](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=6669).

[image]

[Google Translate (mostly) correctly translates the *shinjitai* kanji as "night"](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E6%99%A9).

[image: Correct translation when using U+6669]

However, even though the *kyūjitai* character **has the same meaning**, [Google mistranslates this as "moth" if the source language is set to Japanese](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E6%99%9A).

[image: Mistranslation of U+665A when source language is set to "Japanese"]

When auto-detected, Google [on my machine, anyway] [identifies this as Chinese and translates it as "late"](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E6%99%9A).

[image: Correct translation of U+665A when source language is auto-detected as "Chinese"]

Truly, *[caveat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caveo#Verb) [usuarius](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/usuarius#Noun)*.

Comment: That's a great point, in seeing that more and more these generic translation services fail as you learn more. I've used Jisho! Going to use that over the translation apps from now on.

Comment: Why do you consider jisho.org to sometimes be "a bit dodgy"?

Comment: @HansPeter, I've run into various cases over the years where an entry at Jisho.org was misleading.  See for instance the [discussion at the 唵 entry on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:%E5%94%B5).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... Why were moths brought up?

Comment: @Leebo: I should have grabbed a screen capture -- as of this morning, [Google Translate for 晩](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E6%99%A9) was producing an English "translation" of **moth**.  It seems they might have been having system trouble, or someone corrected the data, as it's now correctly translating this kanji as **evening**.

Comment: @Leebo -- aha, it's doing it for the alternative-form kyūjitai kanji [晚](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E6%99%9A).

Comment: Ah, somehow I just missed that in the OP even after reading the answer and getting confused.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi You should post a screenshot of the error in case Google fixes this. For posterity

Comment: @Ringil, I've got screenshots as local files, but I'm not sure where to upload them. Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi If you copy the image onto your clipboard, you can just paste it into your answer. (or upload it).

Comment: A note on the Chinese: The stand-alone character「晚」is indeed used as *late* or *later* in standard Mandarin. *Night* as a stand-alone word is expressed through the disyllabic「晚上」. The Chinese and Japanese meanings of「晚」are congruent.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi That happens with many single characters that dont have a kunyomi reading.

Comment: FWIW, everyone can suggest an edit for the translation on Google Translate now. It's now [crowdsourced](https://translate.google.com/community?source=mfooter#ja/en), which might improve or worsen the translation...